# add fields together and then update field in different table

Tags: mysql, sum, sql-update, addition

I have two tables in a database - one table creates a maintenance list and the other table is for saving parts. Each maintenance list can have many parts. 
I need to add up the Amount field from the parts table and update the part field in the maintenance table.

Maintenance table:
[image]

Parts table:

[image]

The `ID` from the maintenance table is equal to the `MaintenanceID` field in the parts table. So how do I add the `Amount` together then update the `Parts` field?
So in this example I need to add 135 + 55 then put the answer of 190 into the Parts field.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [ask]. Remember **SO is not a free code service!**

Comment: you are not following the "Third normal form": "Each attribute must represent a fact about the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key."

Comment: So you shouldn´t put the total price as a field.

Comment: if you need it in a query, you could a select with a join